# JS: loop trough String and add object with value of these words (one for one) to an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

I got a String (*var tags*), its words are seperated by a comma

```
var msg ='#yeah alter #wow #cool dadadda'

function listTags(){
if(!tagsss.some(r=> msg.indexOf(r) >= 0))
    (tagsss).push(msg.match(/#\w+/g).map(v => v.replace('#', '')))
return (msg.match(/#\w+/g).map(v => v.replace('#', '')))
}
var tags = listTags().toString() // result: yeah,wow,cool
```

And I got an Array of objects

```
var arrOfObj = [
     { key: 'Sarah', value: 'Sarah' },
     { key: 'Evan', value: 'Evan' },
     { key: 'Adam', value: 'Adam' }
 ]
```

How can I loop trough my string and create for each word a new object inside of my *arrOfObj*. So for every single word (lets call it `x`) I would like to add such an object:
`{key: x, value: x }`

So in my example the result after the first loop would be

```
var arrOfObj = [
     { key: 'Sarah', value: 'Sarah' },
     { key: 'Evan', value: 'Evan' },
     { key: 'Adam', value: 'Adam' },
     { key: 'yeah', value: 'yeah' }
 ]
```

(If one knows a better way to filter the hashtags let me know, but my primary concern is what I mentioned above, Many thanks in advance )

Comment: What is the purpuse to have an object with two properties with the same value ? You should edit your question with more details.

Comment: it's because of a certain plugin where you can differ between a displayed value and the actual value. I don't want them to differ, but the plugin requires them both (key & value).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In newer browsers, you can lookbehind for `#`, map the array of strings to an array of objects and then simply `concat` with the original array:

```js
var arrOfObj = [
     { key: 'Sarah', value: 'Sarah' },
     { key: 'Evan', value: 'Evan' },
     { key: 'Adam', value: 'Adam' }
 ];

var msg ='#yeah alter #wow #cool dadadda';
const result = arrOfObj.concat(
  msg
    .match(/(?<=#)\w+/g)
    .map(key => ({ key, value: key }))
);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Do you know how I could prevent it from inserting an already existing object?

Comment: Best way would be to use an object indexed by `key` instead of an array, and then check whether `obj[key]` exists first - to turn that object back into an array, call `Object.values` on it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see the purpose of repeating the same value with two different keys per object, but you can easily achieve that with the JS array map function:

```js
    var tags = 'banana,pineapple,passionfruit,durian,jackfruit';
    var arrOfObj = [ { key: 'Sarah', value: 'Sarah' },
                     { key: 'Evan', value: 'Evan' },
                     { key: 'Adam', value: 'Adam' } ];
    var objArr = tags.split(',').map( a => {
                 return {key: a, value: a};
                 });
    
    console.log(arrOfObj.concat(objArr))
```

Comment: thanks, it's because of a certain plugin where you can differ between a displayed value and the actual value. I don't want them to differ, but the plugin requires them both (key & value).

Do you know how I could prevent it from inserting an already existing object?